# Certification fails for Windows Store App with ATL-based library

Tags: c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, atl

I have a Windows library developed in C++ that uses ATL collections, ATL CString and COM interfaces with CComPtr heavily. I removed all non-winrt-allowed API calls from the library, and it builds fine, so I wrapped the library in a C++/CX ref-class and I am trying to use it from a Windows Store App. The application runs fine, but the Win-Store App certification fails with the following error:

> Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
>   API GetModuleHandleW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. MyLibrary.dll calls this API. API
>   InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount in kernel32.dll is not supported
>   for this application type. MyLibrary.dll calls this API.

The VS project for my library is configured for Windows Store with the following settings:

[image]

These settings activate/deactivate the required macros (WINAPI_FAMILY as WINAPI_FAMILY_APP for example) in the SDK as expected.

I am 100% sure I am not calling GetModuleHandleW or InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount *directly* in my library, so I thought this issue must be coming from a method of some ATL class that was not filtered properly in the Windows 8 SDK.

Diving into ATL header files was not very useful, since everything *looks* properly filtered there, for example see this fragment from ATL::CComCriticalSection::Init

```
#if !defined(_ATL_USE_WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP) || defined(_ATL_STATIC_LIB_IMPL)
        if (!_AtlInitializeCriticalSectionEx(&m_sec, 0, 0))
#else
        if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&m_sec, 0))
#endif
```

In order to prove my theory, I took an hex-editor and edited out GetModuleHandleW from my Kernel32.lib file, which gives me the following linking error:

> atls.lib(atlwinverapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__GetModuleHandleW@4

So it seems my theory is not wrong. Note that I am doing all this using release builds, since debug builds do not pass the certification.

Now the question:

**Is there any way for me to know exactly which class inside ATL is sabotaging my library other than looking at the header files?**

Same question in [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/1588e531-86a6-4087-a963-6cf4a09d7487/#1588e531-86a6-4087-a963-6cf4a09d7487)

I have added a [bug report on microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774871/certification-fails-for-windows-store-app-with-atl-based-library#details) with a small sample code that reproduces this issue.

Comment: When you include the ATL headers in your library, are you correctly setting the WINAPI_FAMILY macro to WINAPI_FAMILY_APP?

Comment: @James MacNellis The project for the library is configured for Windows Store, I assumed that was enough and that it would activate the required macros, but I will give this a try anyway tomorrow, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I tried your suggestion but nothing changed, please let me know if you have any other hint that can help me. Thanks

Comment: @yms I think your usage of ATL headers is WACK-clean but one of the API you are using from atls.lib (the static lib) is ending up using some non-compliant API which then gets embedded into your own binary.  I wonder what exactly from atls.lib is used by your binary?  I notice that atls.lib is pulled in by default in atlbase.h:  #pragma comment(lib, "atls.lib")

Comment: @SometimesADeveloper I think I found the culprit, I think it is the class 'CComCritSecLock', I have to double check.

Comment: When you link ATL statically then you are going to pull in AtlUpdateRegistryFromResourceD().  Which unfortunately is in the same translation unit as DllMain(), atl.cpp.  I'd post this at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @HansPassant As far as I know linking dynamically is not allowed for Windows Store Apps (I got a warning when I tried). What are my choices then? (and I have a feeling that I will not like your answer...)

Comment: You are right.  I'd much prefer Microsoft giving you the bad news of course.

Comment: By the way I also tried creating a small sample app that uses a library with few ATL classes like CAtlArray, CStringW it did pass the WACK verification. Adding CComCritSecLock however made it fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I guess.  Look at the file atlwinverapi.h.  There the macro _ATL_NTDDI_MIN is conditionally defined one way for x86/x64 and another way for ARM.

I think this might have changed during the recent VSUpdate that added XP support.  Now in the file atlwinverapi.cpp (which goes into atls.lib I guess), in the method _AtlInitializeCriticalSectionEx, you will notice that it's calling InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount if _ATL_NTDDI_MIN < NTDDI_VISTA.

I am assuming your building x86 or x64 that's why you are seeing this problem.  If you build for ARM, you will not see this problem.

Of course you will not be able to run WACK on ARM but you can run dumpbin /imports on your binary and see if it still uses those non-compliant API.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will take a deeper look on this tomorrow and let you know how it went.

Comment: It is as you said, the ARM build does not use the forbidden functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added a [bug report on microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774871/certification-fails-for-windows-store-app-with-atl-based-library#details) with a small sample code that reproduces this issue.

Comment: Since you have effectively identified the bug I will select this as answer, although my problem is not completely solved yet. Let's hope that Microsoft will fix this problem sometime soon.